# Android obfuscating with Proguard Problems

Tags: java, android, jackson, proguard

I'm new to the whole obfuscating with Android thing, but I've started to try out Proguard the last days. Anyway, I'm stucked in the so called Proguard hell.

The structure of my app is that I have 3 different projects. One library and two application projects. Both of the application projects are based on the library project which contains all of the logic and libraries for the applications. Almost nothing is placed in the application projects.

But, when I try to export one of the applications with Proguard enabled I get some errors with the Jackson JSON Parsing library. I've tried alot of different things and I even tried to ignore the errors but that just made the parsing part failed. So ignoring the errors is not the right thing to do.

This is my proguard-project.txt file

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
-keep public class com.google.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
```

And these are the errors that I get.

```
Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateTimeSerializer: 
  can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 99 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `-keep` option for joda time classes:

```
-keep public class org.joda.time.** {public private protected *;}
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
```

Comment: Great dude, that solved like 95% of the warnings but there are 4 more of them, they all looks like this. Warning: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry

Comment: Try to also add -keep and -dontwarn for org.w3c.** and other external libraries. In my project i tried to use different options including -libraryjars and -injars but I had no luck so I had to keep all packages from external libraries(even if my app didn't use them directly). Also if you manage to export your app be aware that it can still crash at runtime because of obfuscated DTO classes, methods called by reflection etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to proguard itself, one thing to do is to make sure you use Jackson 2.x, not 1.x -- it has fewer dynamic (optional) dependencies. This reduces noise by PG.

Answer (score 0):

"Can't find referenced class" means that the JAR files containing these classes need to be specified with `-libraryjars`, which works much like in `javac`'s classpath.